# Java project - kind of a car configurator

Tags: java, list, class, multiple-inheritance

I have a homework for one of my university courses (Special Java Chapters - to be more specific). 
I have to do a program which has to simulate a car configurator - so i have two car models from a manufacturer , each car has a fixed price and multiple options. 
Each option can have a description and a price (ex: engine - price/HP/cm3/fuelCons) . 
I decided to make two classes : one for the model with name and final price and another class for options with multiple inherited classes for each option in part.

In the end i have to make a menu so each customer can be able to add or remove any option (an aleardy added one) and show the final price --something like [this](http://www.dacia.co.uk/vehicles/sandero/configurator/) (it's about the same brand).

I don't know exactly how to do that menu.

Comment: sorry if i wasn't more explicit. I need an idea for how to do the final menu so i can add or remove any option i want. Display the available options , choose what i want and be able to remove an already added option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 'Options' can have several abilities, a native type is not enough. Therefore you have to create another class 'Option' and add fields like description, price, title, etc.

```
class Option {
    private String description;
    private double price;
    ...
}
```

Create a class Car or CarModel to put in the title, etc and add a list of options:

```
class Car {
  ...
     private final double FIXED_PRICE;
  ...
     List<Option> options = new ArrayList<Option>();
  ...
     public Car(final double price) {
       this.FIXED_PRICE  = price;
     }
}
```

To make a price a constant is very uncommon, but maybe ok in our case. To assign a final field at class initializaiton you need to add a constructor like that one shown above.

You also need to add methods for adding and removing options:

```
public void addOption(Option option) {...}
public void removeOption(Option option) {...}
```

If a type of Option can only exist once in your options list you can make it a Set. To calculate the final price add a method that is iterating your options list and summing the prices with the fixed price from the car.

Comment: My car class looks like this : 
    ` 
    ` < public class Dacia {
    
     private String model;
     private final double price;
     
     public Dacia () 
     {
      model = " ";
      price = 0;
     }
     
     public Dacia (String mod , double p)
     {
      model = mod;
       price = p;
 }

 public String getModel() 
 {
  return model;
 }
> `

and the one for otions

    ` < public class Option {
 private String optname,description;
 private double optprice;
 
 public Option () { .. }
        public Option (String name,String desc,double price) { .. }
 > `
 and get/set methods